# Jquery get html or text just after the input tag inside label

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a label as

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="160">160
</label>
```

or it could be as like

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="-160-"><del>160</del>
</label>
```

Now, what I am trying is:

```
var text = $(this).find('label').html();
```

But this is returning whole `<input type="checkbox" value="-160-"><del>160</del>`, which is not I wanted. I have also tried with `.text()` but text is not returning `<del>` tag as well (i.e, it is returning just 160).

I have also tried with `contents().eq(1)`, but with no success. I want to trim input tag or get everything inside the label tag and after input tag

Expected output:

`<del>160</del>` in case of `<input type="checkbox" value="-160-"><del>160</del>`

and

`160` in case of
`<input type="checkbox" value="160">160`

Comment: try this var text = $(this).find('label, del').text();

Comment: what result do you want to get? return `<del> 160 </del>`?

Comment: @Ankit I don't think it will return the `del` tag

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I have added expected output, hope it will makes you clear.

Comment: you want del tag or text of del tag

Comment: @Ankit I want it with del tag, if there it is i.e, tag and text `<del>160</del>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the next sibling node to the `input`, and then check to see if it is a HTML node and if so, return the `outerHTML`, otherwise return the `textContent` of the node.

```js
function getContents(label) {
  let next = $(label).find('input')[0].nextSibling;
  while (!next.outerHTML && next.textContent.trim().length == 0) {
  next = next.nextSibling;
}
  return next.outerHTML ? next.outerHTML : next.textContent;
  }
  
console.log(getContents('#div1 label'));
console.log(getContents('#div2 label'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="160">160
</label>
</div>
<div id="div2">
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="-160-">
    <del>160</del>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: *...I want to trim input tag or get everything inside the label tag and after input tag...* what if some tags are previous siblings?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey but OP wants what is *after* the input tag

Comment: @Nick Here it seems working fine, but on my project it is showing empty instead of `<del>160</del>` Any suggestion, where should I check.

Comment: Perhaps you have white space before the `del` tag?

Comment: Yes There it is.

Comment: In that case, the first node after the `input` is that whitespace, so this will return that. If that will occur, you should perhaps look at @AbhishekPandey solution as it allows you to iterate over *all* the child nodes of the label and then you can pick whichever ones you need.

Comment: Alternatively you could iterate over nextSibling until you find an HTML node or a non-empty text node e.g. `while (!next.outerHTML && next.textContent.trim().length == 0) next = next.nextSibling;` See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can get every child element of an html tag by using [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes), and you can work with some condition, which tag you wants to keep which not.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("label").forEach(function(item) {
  var _childNodes = item.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < _childNodes.length; i++) {
    console.log(_childNodes[i].outerHTML);
  }
})
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value="-160-"><del>160</del></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

label in html often comes with a for attribute like
this

```html
<input id="test" type="checkbox" value="160"><label for="test">160</label>
```

then your javascript would be

```js
console.log($("label[for='test']").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this solution:

```js
$('.labels label').each(function(i, el){
   let $num = $(el).find('input')[0].nextSibling
   if($num.nodeType == 3) {
    console.log($num.data);
   }else {
    console.log($num);
   }
   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="labels">
  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="-160-"><del>160</del>
  </label>
  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="-160-">160
  </label>
</div>
```